# Has the closed form for expanding functions as sum of exponentials been found?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I was seeing [this truly fascinating video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lldiTpV6gX8) by mu prime math about expanding functions out in terms of exponentials , like something of the form:

$$ f(x) = c_o  + c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{\frac{x}{2} }  + c_3 e^{ \frac{x}{3} }.. $$

Later's at 11:16 Mu prime states that he has not been able to find a closed form for the above coefficients for a general function, however it's been more than a year since the video was posted. Has there been progress on this problem/ is it being discussed in research papers?

Comment: I think the idea doesn't look promising at all since the coefficients doesn't seems to converge.

Comment: How did you conclude that @jjagmath

Comment: Trying some more examples. When one tries to approximate $f(x) = c_0 + c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{x/2} +\cdots + c_n e^{x/n}$ first observe that $c_i$ actually depends on $n$, so we should write $c_i(n)$. When $n$ grows, each $c_i(n)$ take larger and larger values, some of them positive, some of them negative, so it won't be an infinite series representing the function (as in the case of Taylor or Fourier series). Another problem is that for some simple functions $f$, the system of equations becomes inconsistent, so there's no solution when one try to solve for the $c_i$'s.

Comment: Oof, turns out pretty useless then. Thank you for the input though!

Comment: Just for fun, for $z \geq 0$ let $S(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-z/k}/k^2$. $S(0) = \pi^2/6$ and
generally $S^{(p)}(0) = (-1)^{p}\zeta(p + 2)$.
The remainder after $n - 1$ terms is
$R_n(z) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty e^{-z/k}/k^2$. Asymptotically
\begin{align*}
        R_n(z) &= \sum_{k=n}^\infty e^{-z/k}/k^2 \\
                &\approx \int_n^\infty e^{-z/k} / k^2 \, dk \\
                &= (1 - e^{-z/n})/z.
\end{align*}